# Error when defining a @hasMany relationship with an interface in AWS Amplify GraphQL schema

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

I have this simple schema:

```
type Student @model {
  username: String!
  firstName: String!
  lastName: String!
  chats: [Chat] @hasMany
}

type Teacher @model {
  username: String!
  firstName: String!
  lastName: String!
  chats: [Chat] @hasMany
}

union User = Student | Teacher

type Chat @model {
  users: [User!]! @hasMany
  messages: [Message] @hasMany
}

type Message @model {
  sender: User! @hasOne
  content: String!
  chat: Chat! @belongsTo
  createdAt: AWSDateTime!
}
```

When I do `amplify push` I get this error:

```
 Could not find related type with name User while processing relationships.
```

Could anyone help me figure out what's wrong with the schema? It all looks good to me
I've googled it and it seems to be related to having a `@hasMany`relation with an interface, like this:

```
  users: [User!]! @hasMany
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy this example from the [AWS Amplify example](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/data-modeling/#has-many-relationship):

```
type Post @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  comments: [Comment] @hasMany
}

type Comment @model {
  id: ID!
  content: String!
}
```

**You do not need:**

1. `belongsTo`
2. `@hasOne`

Comment: Even after removing all `@belongsTo` and `@hasOne` I still get the same error

Comment: Are you testing in AppSync?

Comment: I am using Amplify's CLI

Comment: Go to AppSync in the console, go to your environment, go to queries, and test the code there. Be sure to run `amplify push api -y` for your changes to take effect.